# Block Websites at Work

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, web-filtering

At work there are about 40 PCs. I want to block all the websites and only allow a few Domains/Websites for operators. A few operators can access anything.

I want something quick and easy so I can filter the Block/Allow websites for all computers from one main computer, like a server or something.

Windows Vista Home and Windows 7 Home are installed on the PCs. **Is there any software can do this?**

PS: Please don't answer about Microsoft Windows Server OS..

Comment: Suggestion: You write you want something `like a server`, but specify not Windows server. Would Linux work?

Answer (score 2):

We've had good luck using Untangle:

http://www.untangle.com/

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, a proxy is the only viable option.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Then every operator must have their unique username/password and you can specify individual accesslists per user.

Comment: Is there something control the filters using Computer Name (Network).

Comment: @user791022 - Sure but its hardware and its not cheap.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Kent, so as an alternative you can set up some rules in some routers but it really depends on how advanced your router is.

I have seen instances where you can provide a list of block sites by a text file which the router reads. You then set an IP range which allows those few users to filter through (assuming you can set static IP addresses) - I can't remember the name of the router as it was done in hour Hong Kong branch and wasn't a make I recognised.

Comment: Forget about routers. I want to be done via software. Is there something control the filters using Computer Name (Network).

Comment: If you don't want it on the router then this could be handled by software installed on each PC - depending on the software, updates may be really difficult to control, coupled with all software can be disabled so I don't recommend it! Hardware may work but I don't know of any, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quickly and easily with http://www.opendns.com

All you have to do is:

1. Sign up for a free account
2. Register your public IP address from your ISP
3. Configure what sites and such to block
4. Configure the ISP "device" (maybe a wireless router, cable modem, or whatever) to use the openDNS IP as its WAN DNS server.
5. The "exception" operators you can manually add the 8.8.8.8 or 4.2.2.2 public DNS server so they can get to whatever they want.